# SQL: GROUP BY with string data

Tags: sql, string, group-by

What aggregate functions work on a string, when using a GROUP BY?

I would usually GROUP BY user_id, but I am not sure what aggregate function can work over a string.

Goal is to get the currency for each user_id as one row:

```
user_id   currency

12341235  "USD"
12341235  "USD"
12341235  "USD"
12341235  "USD"
05945949  "EURO"
05945949  "EURO"
05945949  "EURO"
99910277  "USD"
99910277  "USD"
99910277  "USD"
```

Finished data:

```
user_id   currency

12341235  "USD"
05945949  "EURO"
99910277  "USD"
```

Comment: I used dates in the example, but the type is stored as a STRING, and due to the database (Hive) it cannot be turned into a date type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/60ea7/5

A DISTINCT and GROUP BY usually generate the same query plan, so performance should be the same across both query constructs. GROUP BY should be used to apply aggregate operators to each group. If all you need is to remove duplicates then use DISTINCT. If you are using sub-queries execution plan for that query varies so in that case you need to check the execution plan before making decision of which is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need `group by` it can be done by `distinct`.

```
select distinct user_id,currency from your_table;
```

As you have same `currency` for one `user` at each row, here is no need of any `aggregate function`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you want to use group by?

To get the same result you should be able to use DISTINCT, e.g.

Select Distinct user_id, currency

Answer (score 1):

Group bny all columns make it Distinct

```
select user_id,currency from your_table
Group by user_id,currency
```